# How to access photo via Instagram Basic Display API when post is created in collaboration with other profile?

Tags: reactjs, instagram

As in title. I'm using Instagram Basic Display API to retrieve posts from profile. It is generally working, but only with posts created solo. When the post is created in collaboration with other profile it is ignored by API. Any ideas how to deal with it?

I was following this tutorial: https://cming0721.medium.com/instagram-feeds-with-instagram-api-part-2-basic-display-api-with-react-f0c6dfcc576c

When I'm doing call via postman it is also not retrieving collaboration posts.

Is it possible that it's because my app isn't authenticated?
Is it even possible to retrieve collaborative posts?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @xinote I am facing the same issue calling official api https://graph.instagram.com/me/media doesn't return medias published with collaborators. I cannot find any info about this in Meta documentation. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: @Charlyberthet not really, I'm stuck on that